# Atributo definido como false sale como true

Tags: javascript, html5, entrada

Estoy intentando crear una función en Javascript con la que comprobar los inputs con el atributo required en true.

El problema es que aunque este especificado que es false, el resultado que da es true.

Código de ejemplo:

```js
var serial_no = document.getElementsByName('serial_no')[0];
console.log(serial_no);
console.log(serial_no.required);
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" name="serial_no" placeholder="serial_no" value="" required="false">
</form>
```

¿Existe alguna solución?

[image: The required of Schrödinger]

Comment: @Yonkykong A que te refieres con `comprobar` los imputs? Mirar que valor tiene este? Comprobar si esta rellenado?

Comment: @CristianS9 revisar los inputs uno a uno para ver si tienen required.

Comment: @Yonkykong En que caso necesitarías utilizar esto?  Es decir, el atributo `required` lo pone el propio desarollador para asegurarse de  que no se mande el formulario si los campos con `required` no son rellanados. Necesitas comprobar cuantos campos obligatorios tiene el formulario?

Answer (score 1):

El atributo `required` funciona de la manera boolean de presente o ausente. Esto significa que **si existe, es verdadero, si no existe, es falso**.

Por lo que ponerle `required="false"` no le estas diciendo que no es requerido, le estas diciendo que si que existe el atributo.

Para que no sea requerido simplemente, no lo pongas.

```js
var serial_no = document.getElementsByName('serial_no')[0];
console.log(serial_no.required); //true

serial_no = document.getElementsByName('serial_no')[1];
console.log(serial_no.required);// false

serial_no = document.getElementsByName('serial_no')[2];
console.log(serial_no.required);//  true

serial_no = document.getElementsByName('serial_no')[3];
console.log(serial_no.required);//  true
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" name="serial_no" placeholder="serial_no" value="" required>
  <input type="text" name="serial_no" placeholder="serial_no" value="" >
  <input type="text" name="serial_no" placeholder="serial_no" value="" required="loquesea">
  <input type="text" name="serial_no" placeholder="serial_no" value="" required="">
</form>
```

Este tipo de atributo, es una *atributo booleano*, tal como `checked`, `disabled`,... [aqui la fuente](http://notasjs.blogspot.com/2014/02/atributos-booleanos-en-html.html)